# JSON data to HTML using .html()

Tags: javascript, html, json

The code below is commented throughout. It is my understanding that I'm retrieving the JSON data and passing it to the 'results' div in my HTML view. This actually returns nothing, and it's difficult to debug because I can't output anything to the console.

// Here is how the final url should look:
// api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chicago&APPID=2e76bb25aa22d34ca062d764f4f3114b

```
var weatherSearch = '';
  // weather-search is my html form id. On submit, send the input
  // (which is city name) to the function getWeather.
$('#weather-search').submit(function(event) {
weatherSearch = $('#weatherQuery').val();
event.preventDefault();
getWeather(weatherSearch);
});

  // getWeather has params q (city name), and APPID (API key).
function getWeather(weatherSearch) {
var params = {
        q: weatherSearch,
        APPID: '2e76bb25aa22d34ca062d764f4f3114b'
};
  // This is the url that goes before the params.
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/';
  // Request data using url and params above.
  // Does $.getJSON format the url properly?
$.getJSON(url, params, function(data) {
// Pass JSON data to showWeather function.
        showWeather(data.items);
});
}

function showWeather(weather) {
// Show JSON data (weather) in html div id="weatherResults"
    $('#weatherResults').html(weather);

}
```

Here is the associated HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>weather</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="openweather.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="weather-search">
<input type="text" value="" id="weatherQuery" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<div id="weatherResults">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here's a codepen for the program](http://codepen.io/ManBearPigg/pen/reweME?editors=1111)

Comment: why can't you output to the console?

Comment: output.log for anything returns nothing

Comment: It's console.log()

Comment: You could use the DOM to debug if that doesn't work

Comment: It's console.log not output.log

Comment: Also,

   `$.getJSON(url, data, callback).fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });`

Comment: @rubenwardy Please change your comment into an answer as it provides direct assistance (code) that may assist the OP to find the solution to his problem and, at the very least, should be available for upvoting. +1

Comment: Yeah I know, all of this returns nothing. I'll look into what it means to use the DOM to debug

Comment: I'll link a codepen at the end of my original post

Comment: @PencilCrate Open up your web page in chrome, press ctrl+shift+j to go to dev tools. On the top of the dev tools go to the network tab. Hit the red record button on the top left and refresh the page in your browser. There should be an XHR tab, tap on it and look at the results.

Comment: @zfrish I did that "All" shows my .js and .html pages, but XHR shows nothing. What is XHR?

Comment: Debugging via the dom meant this: `$("#elem").append("debug text");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer demonstrates multiple ways to request and view data.**

The code snippet below queries the web service using either [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) or plain javascript. The returned data is displayed on the screen using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [Google Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). The data is also sent to the console. Interestingly, the [OpenWeatherMap](http://openweathermap.org/api) service makes a good guess when the city name is misspelled.

The problem with OP's code appears to be this line: `showWeather(data.items);` which tries to display an object as html.

**Run the snippet to try**

```js
var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=2e76bb25aa22d34ca062d764f4f3114b';


// plain javascript version

function getWeather(city) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url + '&q=' + city, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      showData( data );
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}


// jQuery version

function getWeather2( city ) {
  $.getJSON(url + '&q=' + city, showData );
}


// display json weather data

function showData( data ) {
  window.city.value = data.name;
  window.stdout.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, false, '  ');
  window.stdout.className = 'prettyprint';
  PR.prettyPrint();
  if (window.console) window.console.log( data );
}


// sample data
getWeather('Berlin');
```

```css
input {border: 1px solid black;}
button {width: 8em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/run_prettify.js?autoload=false&amp;skin=sunburst&amp;lang=js"></script>

Enter City: <input id="city" >
<button onclick="getWeather(window.city.value)">Use JS</button>
<button onclick="getWeather2(window.city.value)">Use jQuery</button>


<pre id="stdout" class="prettyprint"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use console.log or the dom to print messages for debugging. You can run a callback like this to find out if a request fails, this will tell you more infomation:

```
$.getJSON(url, params, function(data) {
        // Pass JSON data to showWeather function.
        showWeather(data.items);
}).fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the complete URL (http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/?q=Chicago&APPID=2e76bb25aa22d34ca062d764f4f3114b) directly in a browser returns some JSON with data about chicago -- but that JSON **does NOT contain an item property**. Thus, your data.items is null and nothing is shown.

Just check what you actually get from the browser and adopt your code accordingly (e.g. data.name would give you "Chicago", or simply use `showWeather(data);` to show all JSON you got).

Comment: Why does this return nothing? $.getJSON(url, params, function(data) { console.log(data.weather) }); Because weather is a valid property so it should return that